how do I define a bean' in your configuration, given the error message i get?
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.predmod.app.service.CompanyService required a bean of type 'com.predmod.app.dao.CompanyDao' that could not be found.
I get this error message im my java application:
Error: The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
- User-defined bean
Action:
Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'com.predmod.app.dao.CompanyDao' in your configuration.
Here is the CompanyService class
package com.predmod.app.service;

import com.predmod.app.dao.CompanyDao;
import com.predmod.app.model.Company;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CompanyService {

    private final CompanyDao companyDao;

    @Autowired
    public CompanyService(@Qualifier("fakeDao") CompanyDao companyDao) {
        this.companyDao = companyDao;
    }

    public int addCompany(Company company) {

        return companyDao.insertCompany(company);
    }
}

and below is the CompanyDao interface
package com.predmod.app.dao;

import com.predmod.app.model.Company;
import java.util.*;

public interface CompanyDao {
    int insertCompany(UUID id, Company company);

    default int insertCompany(Company company) {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        return insertCompany(id, company);
    }


}

and an implementation of the CompanyDao interface
package com.predmod.app.dao;

import com.predmod.app.model.Company;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.*;

@Repository("fakeDaO")
public class FakeCompanyDataAccessServices implements CompanyDao{

    private static List<Company> db = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int insertCompany(UUID id, Company company) {
        db.add(new Company(company.getId(),
                company.getCompanySize(),
                company.getLocation(),
                company.getIndustry(),
                company.getEstYear(),
                company.getAbout(),
                company.getName()));
        return 1;
    }
}

Please how can I resolve this?

how does your main class looks like including package location?
